# How can I make two scripts into one?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Please read the following template:

```
PID     Status      LPID

10       Closed      25
11       Open        25
31       Open        31
25       Closed      25
54       Open        31
17       Open        17
20       Closed      31
88       closed      77
77       closed      77
201      open       202
205      open        500
```

Now when PID!= LPID, that PID is defined as CPID(Child Process ID),Otherwise it is a PPID(Parent process ID)

Now I am looking for a code which will tell which is parent and Which is child- means marking them in another sheet.At the Same time i want to list down all CPID,with PPID in the same row,If any PPID has child Processes themselves. Output would be look like below

```
PID   Type Of Process?    Child List
10       Child
11       Child
31       Parent              54 20
25       Parent              10 11
54       Child
17       Parent
20       Child
88       Child
77       Parent              88
```

I have written a code using VBScript,but with the actual sheet it is too slow. For 2500 data it is taking close to 1 hour.So I Want a more faster process than my one.

Could you help here using VBscript?

***Code1:***

```
  Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")'Object for W2W Report Dump


  strPathExcel1 = "D:\VA\CopyofGEWingtoWing_latest_dump_21112012.xls"
  objExcel1.Workbooks.open strPathExcel1

  Set objSheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
  Set objSheet2 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    IntRow1=1
 Do While objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1, 1).Value <> ""

    IntRow2=4
    IntChildListColumn=3

    If objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,2).Value="Parent" Then

        Do While objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2, 1).Value <> ""

             If objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2,11).Value=objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,1).Value And objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2,11).Value <> objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2,1).Value Then

                 objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,IntChildListColumn).Value=objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2,1).Value
                 IntChildListColumn=IntChildListColumn+1

             End If

      IntRow2=IntRow2+1

      Loop

   End If

 IntRow1=IntRow1+1

Loop
```

***Code2:***

```
 Flag=0
 IntColTemp=1
 IntRowTemp=3

 Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")'Object for Condition Dump


 strPathExcel1 = "D:\VA\CopyofGEWingtoWing_latest_dump_21112012.xls"
 objExcel1.Workbooks.open strPathExcel1

 Set objSheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 Set objSheet2 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

 IntRow1=4
 IntRow2=1

Do While objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1, 1).Value <> ""

  objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2, 1).Value = objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1, 1).Value


   IntColTemp=1
   Flag=0
  'This will travarse to the Parent Business Process ID column horizantally in the excel.
  Do While Flag=0

  If objSheet1.Cells(IntRowTemp,IntColTemp).Value="Parent Business Process ID" Then

      Flag=1       

  End If

      IntColTemp=IntColTemp+1


Loop
      IntColTemp=IntColTemp-1
      'MsgBox(IntColTemp)

  Strcmp1=trim(objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1, 1).Value)
  Strcmp2=trim(objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,IntColTemp).Value)

  If Strcmp1=Strcmp2 Then

      objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2, 2).Value="Parent" 

  Else

      objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2, 2).Value="child"

  End If


   IntRow1=IntRow1+1
   IntRow2=IntRow2+1

  Loop
```

***EDIT*** see the two ID 201 and 205 has the child-parent relationship.But the child id will then needs to present in the output column but parent 202 and 500 should not come to the output list, as there is no enetry in the main table `202  close/open  202` and `500  open/close  500`

Comment: And the code response time should be good!

Comment: if you care about performance then why are you using visual basic?

Comment: As i was requested to do so! Can you help me here?

Comment: I can refine those algorithms that you're using so they run much faster but to do so will require complex data structures which aren't available in VB.

Comment: but how much possible in VBScript please do, it will be helpful for me.but which platform u r suggesting rather?

Comment: You should refactor this using arrays instead of looping through the worksheet cell values.

Comment: May i have a demo code for the same? Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas/strategies:

1. Load the Range into an array instead of accessing the cells ((c) @DanielCook)
2. Use a dictionary if you have to process data about (a set of) elements.

In code:

```
Option Explicit

Class cP
  Public m_sRel
  Public m_dicC
  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_sRel     = "Child"
    Set m_dicC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  End Sub
  Public Function show()
    show = m_sRel & " " & Join(m_dicC.Keys)
  End Function
End Class

Dim oFS   : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oXls  : Set oXls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oWb   : Set oWb  = oXls.Workbooks.Open(oFs.GetAbsolutePathName(".\00.xlsx"))
Dim aData : aData    = oWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$A2:$C10")
Dim dicP  : Set dicP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim nRow
For nRow = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
    Set dicP(aData(nRow, 1)) = New cP
Next

For nRow = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
    If aData(nRow, 1) = aData(nRow, 3) Then
       dicP(aData(nRow, 1)).m_sRel = "Parent"
    Else
       dicP(aData(nRow, 3)).m_dicC(aData(nRow, 1)) = 0
    End If
Next

Dim nP
For Each nP In dicP.Keys()
    WScript.Echo nP, dicP(nP).show()
Next

oWb.Close
oXls.Quit
```

output:

```
10 Child
11 Child
31 Parent 54 20
25 Parent 10 11
54 Child
17 Parent
20 Child
88 Child
77 Parent 88
```

Comment: Hi Ekkehard.Horner, Nice thought you have given to me. But curious to know any good tutorial where i can also read through such things about VBScript strengths and limitations.

Comment: Hi, If i want to store the output data in an Excel sheet,how to frame this,for future reference?

Comment: I need to record these details to an excel sheet which will be processed by other scripts once it will be done!

Comment: what the syntax is to get the child PID one by one,as i need to store them excel columns?

Comment: I am getting an error to the line `dicP(aData(nRow, 3)).m_dicC(aData(nRow, 1)) = 0` `Object required[..]`. Can you please help me here?

Comment: @user1897085: I suspect your Child list contains at least one ID that isn't in the PID column.

Comment: PID always would have both the child and Parent ID always. One scenario can be happened that Child id has a Parent ID in the main table but that parent ID is missing from the PID column.So in such a case we will ignore that PID from the output list.

Comment: Can you please help me here to make the code run as expected ?

Comment: You suspect correctly: I just added 3 lines `       If dicP.Exists(aData(nRow, 2)) Then
    
                dicP(aData(nRow, 2)).m_dicC.Add   aData(nRow, 1), 0        '(aData(nRow, 1)) = 0
      
       End If` and my code started to run. I am happy :-)

Comment: @user1897085: That you have applied something you have learned here to solve a problem on your own makes me really happy. (As English is not my first language, I add: honestly, no irony intended)

Comment: Yeah,I agree- the far I improved myself in this VBScript platform,all credit goes to you all... really awesome Stackoverflow is.......... :-) :-)